# Seaborn Hue - ValueError: Could not interpret input 'type'

Tags: seaborn

Can anyone help with this error?

*File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py", line 142, in establish_variables
    raise ValueError(err)
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'type'*

I have double checked the spelling of the csv header type, also tried renaming the header.

```
#https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html
mydata = sns.load_dataset("iris")
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="petal_length", y="petal_width", hue="type", data=mydata)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no column named "type" in the iris dataset. I think you mean "species".

```
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
iris.columns
>> Index(['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width',
   'species'],
  dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks Diziet Asahi, your solution has fixed it. I didn't realize until you answered this that seaborn had imported its own iris dataset. I thought I was referring seaborn to my own variable iris = pd.read_csv('IRIS.csv'), where I had called the column type. Your solution makes sense to me now. Any ideas how I could get seaborn to use the 'type' from my file column, incase I use other data in future.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you load your data with pd.read_csv() then you would use your own column names in the call to scatterplot

Comment: I guess I am trying to work out why seaborn isn't using the variable that references my spreadsheet and is loading its own dataset. Any ideas how I link my spreadsheet to the code above?

Comment: Just figured it out, thank you again for your help ..    
    mydata = pd.read_csv('IRIS.csv')
    ax = sns.scatterplot(x="petal_length", y="petal_width", hue="type", data=mydata)
    plt.show()